# Chrome Dev Tools Toggle Device Remote Url

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I've found the fantastic Chrome Toggle Device for mobile testing in Chrome.
Is it possible to find out the url that Chrome uses for online testing within the Toggle Device Mobile emulator screen?

I wish to use the Mobile Emulator within a iframe for a specific url.

[Chrome Mobile Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqmgX.gif)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is the same one that is in your omnibar's address area. All Device Mode is doing is hitting that URL but modifying the headers sent to the server to look like the specified device type. And then making the local viewport look like the given device's size.

Comment: Thanks! So everything actually happens locally? Would it be possible to include this technology in an iframe instead of the device view?

Comment: No, it can't be done in an iframe. Device Mode is literally changing the rendering engine to be the one for mobile as much as possible. That kind of conditional switching between iframes is not possible. Among all the other things DevTools is doing for Device Mode.